# Dynamic Key name with in the defined list for a Map in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to define the `type` in typescript.. that should accept at least one key-value (within the defined list). If the data has at least one defined key among the list, remaining should be optional.

Is there any way we can do that in typescript.

```
type values = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd';
type data<T extends string, K> = Record<T, K>;

// current output:
const d:data<values, string> = {
  'a': 'sample text',
  'b': 'b sample text',
  'c': 'c sample text'
};

// Expecting output
const d:data<values, string> = {
  'a': 'sample text'
}
```

In the above example, `d` expects every key in the `values`. I did try `partial` it is making all values are optional.

my intention is when the incoming data should have at least one `key` from the `values`.

Note:
Values are so dynamic or have a longer list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by intersecting a mapped type to require each property individually with `Partial<T>`

```
type AtLeastOne<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        [K2 in K]: T[K]
    }
}[keyof T] & Partial<T>
```

How it works:

1. Loop over all the keys in the provided record, and set the type in the resulting record to be an object with just that key `{ [K in keyof T] ... }`
2. Get the union of all elements in the mapped type `[keyof T]`
3. Intersect the union with `Partial<T>` to require any other provided properties to be the correct type

Demo: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=42#code/C4TwDgpgBAgsAyECGBnYB5AdhAPAFQD4oBeKAbwFgAoKWqAbQGkoBLTKAawhAHsAzKHgC6ALnLU6khowBMrdo1GCmQiXQC+1dfS68BwqADIoABSQAnYCyQAbfAWrVQkKABEkwJDmYQAHsAhMABMUKDRzNgBzABpBIlI4RFQMbBwAJQgAYx5zIO9YwgcqJ3BoRm5Q0gByJCqoAB8oKoAjOsaqzLamoKrHKmdoDJQAVxtgEjcPL3KQFFjwqKLqbMw0KF8xd09vCvngCMxI+PEaOiQxKrqAeiuoHg4tPpW1kE2pndm9g6OJsnUoG5QCDmcw5IA)

```
type AtLeastOne<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        [K2 in K]: T[K]
    }
}[keyof T] & Partial<T>

type Data<K extends string, T> = AtLeastOne<Record<K, T>>

type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd'

type Result = Data<Keys, string>

const x: Data<Keys, string> = {
    a: '' // ok
}

const y: Data<Keys, string> = {} // error
```